# How can I do query which will select GL/Accounts with their amount, Turnover and Operating Costs? SAP B1

Tags: abap, sapb1, opensql

How can I do query which will select GL/Accounts with their amount of Turnover and Operating Costs in Chart of Accounts?

For example

SELECT GL/Account,Amount FROM OACT WHERE their_type='Turnover'

SELECT GL/Account,Amount FROM OACT WHERE their_type='Operating Costs'

I tried to search in OACT table of SAP B1 but there is no column which stores Turnover, Operating Costs or Assets,....

How can I do the above query without set condition of one by one account?

for example

SELECT GL/Account,Amount FROM OACT WHERE AcctCode='0001' or AcctCode='0002' or AcctCode='0003' or AcctCode='0004'

Please anyone can help me

Comment: Firstly, where is the relation, between the account and the turnover stored? Try to elaborate on your question a bit more. Explain the important parts of your application, and try your best to pin-point the problem.

Comment: Hello, do you know SAP B1? if yes, the problem I have is relationship between GL/Accounts and their Types. As it seems in Chart of Accounts there should be relationship but I don't find it in OACT table and other related tables

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will have to join the OACT table with JDT1 that has the amounts.

I am not sure of the Rwandan standard for chart of accounts but you can have something like:

```
SELECT T0.AcctCode, T0.AcctName, T0.FatherNum, SUM(T1.Debit - T1.Credit) * -1 AS 'Amount'
FROM OACT T0
INNER JOIN JDT1 T1 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[Account] 
WHERE T0.AcctCode LIKE '41%' AND T0.Postable = 'Y'
AND (T1.RefDate BETWEEN {?StartDate} AND {?EndDate})

GROUP BY T0.AcctCode, T0.AcctName, T0.FatherNum
```

Above is assuming that all accounts starting with 41 refer to turnover. Also not sure whether all posting you done are done on one level, e.g. 4 or on multiple levels.

Comment: Yes Kinyanjui, I have to use LIKE '33%' in my query. Thank you so much

Comment: 1- Some charts of accounts will not have the same root as the parent account, I have faced this case in many companies.  LIKE '41%' will fail sometimes
2. - you don't need to filter `T0.Postable = 'Y'` because `JDT1` table has no row for non postable accounts.

Answer (score 0):

while accepted answer could have helped you, I would like to let you know that `OACT` has a column nammed `ActType` which values are `E` for expenses or operating costs, `I` for profit or turnover and `N` for none of the Expenses or Profit.

```
SELECT T0.AcctCode, T0.AcctName, T0.FatherNum, SUM(T1.Credit - T1.Debit) AS    
'Balance' FROM JDT1 T1
INNER JOIN OACT T0 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[Account] 
WHERE T0.ActType='I' 
AND (T1.RefDate BETWEEN {?StartDate} AND {?EndDate}) 
GROUP BY T0.AcctCode, T0.AcctName, T0.FatherNum
```

For operating costs

```
SELECT T0.AcctCode, T0.AcctName, T0.FatherNum, SUM(T1.Debit - T1.Credit) AS    
'Balance' FROM JDT1 T1
INNER JOIN OACT T0 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[Account] 
WHERE T0.ActType='E' 
AND (T1.RefDate BETWEEN {?StartDate} AND {?EndDate}) 
GROUP BY T0.AcctCode, T0.AcctName, T0.FatherNum
```

Note that some accounts are both `TurnOver` and `OperatingCost` at the sametime. In this case, their `actType` will be `N`